# Size of short int in 16 bit machine

Tags: c, types

In the book "The C Language" , the only restriction on the integral data types is that

16 bits <= size of short <= size of int  <= size of long  ;
32bits <= size of long

(Edit: FINE, i edited the constraint to remove the confusion with the std function)

and in another book (Programming in ANSI C - Balaguruswamy) , its given that the sizeof(short) in a 16 bit machine is 
8 bits (half of the size of ints which are 16 bits). Isn't this contradicting with the above given constraint?

Comment: At least for standard C, `short` must be at least 16 bits.

Comment: Exactly, so is the latter book wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, some books have errors. Also, some companies produce compilers that they say compile C code, but really can't because the compiler has so many deviations from the C specification (DSPs in particular come to mind as platforms where this sin is popular).

Comment: Any book saying a `short` is less than 16 bits is either wrong, or talking about some language other than standard C.

Comment: @BalaK: It is either flat out wrong or *outdated*. Standard C does not allow 8-bit `short`. But pre-standard C might have.

Comment: Sizeof gives the size in bytes, not bits, so as stated, neither assertion is right.

Comment: @n.m 'sizeof' isnt referred here as a function but merely as a shorthand or notation for size of that data type. :P

Comment: So what's the title and author of the "other" book? And when was it published? My recollection (foggy and hazy though it may be) of programming DOS PC's BackInTheDay (tm), and prior to the first ANSI standard for C, was that int was 16 bits, short was 16 bits, long was 32 bits, and char was 8 bits across all the compilers I used back then (Microsoft, Datalight, Zortech, Borland). Your mileage and compiler might vary from that.

Comment: Actually, arranging integer types in terms of "amount of storage" they occupy (`sizeof`) is a C++ thing. C language never made such claim. C arranges these types in terms of their *ranges*. I.e. range of `short` must be a subrange of `int` and so on. Pedantically speaking, C does not even seem to require `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int)`. It is known as on of those strange and very pedantic differences between C and C++.

Comment: Re-edited to add the book's title. I'm reading the latest edition released not more than a few months ago.

Comment: Time to throw the book away.  If it gets that wrong, it probably has other more serious errors in it too.  And you won't know when it is misleading you because you don't know enough C yet.  (And if it is written by your course tutor, it might be time to ask for a refund and find someone else who can teach it).

Comment: @JohnZwinck The question is about C and not C++. Even though standards might not differ substantially on this matter, they are completely different languages with separate standards. SO uses a tag system. If a question asks about `c` the dup should be market with at least the same tag. In the future please close with the correct tag. Thank you.

Comment: I have to remind everyone again the difference between width and size. Width is directly related to range but size could be padded arbitrarily larger than width. Also note that standard c uses neither to regulate char/short/int/long/long long because the representation is implementation defined, so is the relationship between range and width. Standard only specify the range those types can hold, without restricting how many bits they use or bytes to store them.